# What is the most conclusive javascript benchmark test?

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

Here's four of them:

SunSpider JavaScript 0.9.1
V8 Benchmark Suite
Peacekeeper
Kraken 1.0

Different benchmarks tend to show a different browser as the king. Which one (including any one I may not have listed) is the most conclusive benchmark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sports analysts will never agree as to who is/was the best soccer player in history. Maradona? Pelé? Cruyff? Another one?

Different people regard some characteristics as more important than others, and give them more weight when forming an opinion. Same happens with benchmarks: **no benchmark is absolutely right**.

Find **the benchmark that values the characteristics that you think are important for your particular program**, and trust that one.

Comment: It's obviously David Beckham as measured by my `FormerSpiceGirlMarriages` benchmark

Comment: @Daniel HAHAHA and here I was just needing someone to remind me life wasn't boring. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The one that does exactly what your application does.